# A Perfect Square formula

Tags: number-theory

I have a formula for perfect square.
$$ 12\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{6}+(n-1)(1\cdot2)+(n-2)(2\cdot3)+(n-3)(3\cdot4)+(n-4)(4\cdot5)+\cdots+(n-1)n\right]$$

For any value of $n$ where $n \in N$

Answer will be a perfect Square
For Example  put $$n=5$$
$$ =12\left[\frac{5(6)}{6}+(5-1)(1\cdot2)+(5-2)(2\cdot3)+(5-3)(3\cdot4)+(5-4)(4\cdot5)+(5-5)(5\cdot5)\right]$$
$$ =12[5+8+18+24+20+0]$$
$$ =900$$
Where 900 is a perfect square

Question:
Is there any reason Behind in it?

Since $$ 3\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{6}+(n-1)(1\cdot2)+(n-2)(2\cdot3)+(n-3)(3\cdot4)+(n-4)(4\cdot5)...(n-1)n\right] \\= 1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3.....n^3$$

Comment: The last term in your formula doesn't match the pattern of the previous terms shown. And doesn't match your example, either. Could you please clarify?

Comment: $\Sigma$ notation form:

$$12\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{6} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}(n-i)i(i+1) \right]$$

Comment: Did you mean $$ (n-1)n$$ term? for 5 $$ (n-1)n= (5-1)(5)=20=(n-4)(4*5)$$ so i did stop on $$ (n-4)(4*5) $$ because  $$(5-1)(5)=(5-4)(4*5)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me see what happened. We have

$$12\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{6}  + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k)k(k+1)\right] = 12\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{6}  + n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k(k+1) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^3 - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^2\right] = 12\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{6}  + n \left( \frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6} + \frac{(n-1)n}{2}\right) - \frac{(n-1)^2n^2}{4} - \frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}\right] = 12\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{6} + \frac{n^2(n-1)}{12}(4n-2 - 3n+3) + \frac{n(n-1)}{6}(3n-2n+1)\right] = 12\frac{n(n+1)}{6}\left(1+\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + n-1\right) = n^2(n+1)^2.$$

Comment: $$ 3\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{6} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}(n-i)i(i+1) \right] = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} $$ $$3\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{6} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}(n-i)i(i+1) \right]$$ is the New Expression for $$ 1^3+2^3+3^3.....n^3$$

Answer (score -1):

$\sum_{i=1}^n{i^3}=(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$

Comment: this is not the same as the formula given (1)

Comment: @NikosM. this answer assume the OP has proved his last equation present in his post.